# Building Dynamic Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a dynamic query in an application which sends from the front to the back some parameters, and then a expression is built with that parameters.

I basically have two main classes that do all the work. A generic class that concatenate expressions (called PredicateBuilder) and a class that uses it to build the expression itself.

#### PredicateBuilder

```
    public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                             Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        }
    }
```

#### CustomPredicateBuilder

```
    public class CustomPredicateBuilder
    {
        public Expression<Func<Ticket, bool>> Build(DtoTicketFilter filter)
        {
            var expression = PredicateBuilder.True<Ticket>();

            // APPROACH 1 - Get an exception
            expression = expression.And(a => filter.IncludeWords.Select(b => a.Content.Contains(b)).Aggregate((c, d) => c && d));

            // APPROACH 2 - It works
            foreach (var word in filter.IncludeWords)
                expression = expression.And(x => x.Content.Contains(word.ToLower()));

            return expression;
        }
    }
```

As I showed I tried 2 approaches, and when I use the first one in a query I get and exception. `variable 'b' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`.

I just want to know why I get that exception and how to solve it.

Comment: I answered a similar question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105811/building-dynamic-query-in-a-loop-using-expression-trees/46106541#46106541